# How to extract specific text from string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a string in 
'OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:TDEP],OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:RDEP]' format and output has to be TDEP,RDEP what is the efficient way to extract?

```
test = 'OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:TDEP],OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:RDEP]'
test1 = test.replace('OBNAME','')
test2 = test1.split(',')
for dd in test2 :
    #print(dd)
    test4 = dd.split('identifier:')
    test5 = test4[1]
    channels = channels +','+ test5.replace(']','')
print(channels)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex: `identifier:(.*?)]`

This is the code generated on regex101.com:

https://regex101.com/r/t5ToQK/1

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"identifier:(.*?)]"

test_str = "'OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:TDEP],OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:RDEP]'"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we could use a simple expression with a capturing group and collect our desired outputs, then we join them with a comma:

```
identifier:(\s+)?(.*?)(\s+)?\]
```

if the whitespace might be undesired, otherwise, we could simplify it to:

```
identifier:(.*?)\]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/riZJJY/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"identifier:(\s+)?(.*?)(\s+)?\]"

test_str = ("OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:TDEP],OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:RDEP]\n\n"
    "OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier: TDEP  ],OBNAME[origin:85 copy:1 identifier:  RDEP  ]")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tpomUy/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: why are you capturing whitespaces may I ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single capturing group and a negated character class to match not a `]`:

```
\bidentifier:([^]]+)\]
```

That will match:

- `\bidentifer:` Match identifier: preceded by a word boundary
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^]]+` Match 1+ times not a `]`
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThGlQc/1)